# Color not working on active button

Tags: html, css, button, pseudo-class

I am trying to get the css font color to change to white when a button is pressed, however the only way I can currently do this is if I use !important and force the color to change. Is there a way to do this without using !important? Here is my code:

Currently the button font color changes to the background color of .modal-close, unless I use !important to force it to change to white. Is there any way to make this work properly without using !important? Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.modal-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: 1px solid $gray-light;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.modal-close-x {
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
.modal-close:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
.modal-close:active {
    background: #41b97c;
    color: #ffffff; /* want this to work without !important */
    border: 1px solid #41b97c;
}
.modal-close:hover {
    border: 1px solid #41b97c;
    color: #41b97c;
}
```

```html
<button  class="modal-close pull-right" aria-label="Close" >
    <span class="modal-close-x" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: `:modal-close:active` and `.modal-close:hover` have the same specificity. So the later one takes precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a matter of  selectors ordering  <sup>(*which should ALWAYS  follow [**LOVE and HATE**](https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/)*)</sup> given CSS specificity are the same the cascade part of CSS will take care of it and make the last rule override the priors.

How [**LOVE and HATE**](https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/) should be ordered:

```css
a:link
a:visited
a:hover /* Note that `a:focus` is the same order level as `a:hover` */
a:active
```

so in your case, should be:

```css
.modal-close:focus {}
.modal-close:hover {}
.modal-close:active {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of your `:hover` and `:active` defs

```css
.modal-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: 1px solid $gray-light;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.modal-close-x {
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
.modal-close:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.modal-close:hover {
    border: 1px solid #41b97c;
    color: #41b97c;
}
.modal-close:active {
    background: #41b97c;
    color: #ffffff; /* want this to work without !important */
    border: 1px solid #41b97c;
}
```

```html
<button  class="modal-close pull-right" aria-label="Close" >
    <span class="modal-close-x" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the :active after the :hover in the CSS to add more priority to it and override the :hover class :

```css
.modal-close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid $gray-light;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.modal-close-x {
  position: relative;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.modal-close:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


.modal-close:hover {
  border: 1px solid #41b97c;
  color: #41b97c;
}
.modal-close:active {
  background: #41b97c;
  color: #ffffff;
 /* border: 1px solid #41b97c; also no need this style as it's already defined on hover */
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-close pull-right" aria-label="Close">
    <span class="modal-close-x" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the browser reads top to bottom with the ones at the top applied first and the ones at the bottom applied last, you can simply put .modal-close:active at the bottom of your CSS like so:

```
.modal-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius:30px;
    border: 1px solid $gray-light;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
.modal-close-x {
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
.modal-close:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
.modal-close:hover {
    border: 1px solid #41b97c;
    color: #41b97c;
}
.modal-close:active {
    background: #41b97c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #41b97c;
}
```